# Android SQL Database with special characters, can't access

Tags: android, sql, csv, sqlite

I have an APP which is shipped with a pre-existing SQL database. I use the SQLiteAssetHelper(https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) lib to manage this pre-existing database. In order to populate the database I used the .import command of the sqlite3.exe command line program. My database is in .csv file format. Everything works fine if my .csv file is in ANSI format (which does not support characters like é ú ã). However when I save my .csv file (through notepad) and choose the UTF-8 encoding, my app crashes. I import ok with sqlite3.exe, I even check with SQLite Database Browser and all the information is imported to the database ok. However in Android the following error occurs:

```
05-20 16:05:50.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.baianos.quizbaianos/com.baianos.quizbaianos.QuestionActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

The code that does the query in my app is:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = 
            db.query(DB_NAME, // a. table
            COLUMNS, // b. column names
            " _id = ?", // c. selections 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(1);
```

It seems that my query is not returning any rows because when I pass 'id = 1' (or any other number) and this is compared with the database, the 1 coming from android is different than the 1 in the sql database (because of the different encodings).
How do I tell in code that I am using UTF-8 in the database?

Comment: `1` is the same in ANSI and UTF-8.

Comment: I don't know what the error is then... But I am passing String.valueOf(1) as argument and the query is returning nothing. However when I save my .csv file in ANSI format in notepad and then import this to the database everything works normal! But in this case I can't use é á à characters!

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE _id = '1'` work in the command-line shell in both cases?

Comment: CL Thanks a lot. When I was testing your answer I realized that the error was on the .import feature from the sqlite3.exe tool. Even though the SQLite Database Browser was showing everything okay the very first line of the database was bugged in the ID column. So I manually corrected it and everything is working fine now, with accents. Thank you!